# How to put an execution time limit for MySQL Temporary table creation

Tags: mysql, sql, timeout

We can use `SET MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=10;` statement to stop the execution of a `SELECT` statement, if it took more than 10 milliseconds to execute the query. But the same wont work for other statements like `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-execution-time

Currently my temporary table creation takes more than 50s to complete. I want to put a limit like 10s. Is it possible in MySQL?